# Android Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, xml, manifest

im new here (at Stackoverflow and programming android) and just gotten an error thats not covered in my education books etc. Maybe you could cover it, i would be very happy:). Something went wrong with my Manifest thats covered in app->search->main. Heres the Code. One Error is Android Studio showing me at line 92:  cause theres no constructor but i guess thats not neccessary.. (i got this error to when i want to install it even when i delete this).

So here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.plaetzmueller.yourworkoutplanner">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".ActiveWorkout"
            android:label="@string/ActiveWorkout"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".HomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AddAWorkoutScreen"
            android:label="@string/AddWorkoutPlan"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Excercises"
            android:label="@string/Excercises"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ProgressScreen"
            android:label="@string/Progress"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".VideoScreen"
            android:label="@string/Videos"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FriendList"
            android:label="@string/Friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TrophyActivity"
            android:label="@string/Trophys"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SeeMoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/SeeMore"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SQLHelper" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoScreenNutrion" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoScreenExerciseExecution" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoScreenStretchingAndWarmingUp" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoScreenHowTo"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that classes which you've registered as activities really extend Activity. At least I'd be surprised if .SQLHelper is instance of Activity.  Than remove all redundant declarations.

Comment: Okay. The manifest automatically added this. How do i handle something (for example) that extended AppCompatiblity or SQLiteOpen Helper

                                                                                                                            
________________________________________________________public class ActiveWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {

public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

Comment: Please read what should be included into manifest file here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html. Another classes shouldn't be declared here.

Comment: AppCompatActivity is Activity instance and should be included. SQLHelper is not and shouldn't be declared within your manifest.

Comment: as i said if i delete this entry i have the same problem :/

Comment: btw i found the error... i missed one line--> android:value=